# php - codeigniter - Undefined property loading form helper

Tags: php, codeigniter, load, undefined, helper

i have the following code for create a class but when the class with his costructor get load i get an error:

```
    Class DropDown {
        public function __construct() 
        {
            if ( ! function_exists('form'))
            {
(line 11)   $this->load->helper('form');
            }
        }
```

and the error

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message: Undefined property: DropDown::$load

Filename: helpers/dropdown_helper.php

Line Number: 11
```

Thanks all in advance

Answer (score 0):

You have to assign the CodeIgniter object to a variable:

```
$CI =& get_instance();
$CI->load->helper('form');
```

If you dont want to use `$CI`, you can continue with `$this`.

Just add `__get` method to your class and you can use `$this->load` format.

```
public function __get($var)
{
   return get_instance()->$var;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

DropDown is what? you have to extend CI_*, you cant use $this->load, there is no such function in your class.

Or use $CI = &get_instance(); and then replace $this with $CI

Answer (score 0):

instead of the answer by **Bora** you can extend `CI controller` like this

```
Class DropDown extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() 
    {
        if ( ! function_exists('form'))
        {
             $this->load->helper('form');
        }
    }
```